# Django Rest Framework: 'estado' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF and i get this TypeError with a nested serialization. I have read the [Documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#serializers) but I still can't resolve my problem.

**Models:**

```
class Estado(models.Model): 
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.estado

class Municipio(models.Model):
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado)
    municipio = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.municipio

class Usuario(models.Model):    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado)
    municipio = models.ForeignKey(Municipio) 
    donador = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**Serializer:**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email')

class UsuarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'estado', 'municipio')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Usuario.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user
```

I'm trying to create an "Usuario" model that is a user's profile.

Answer (score 2):

Did not test this, but you probably need to set a related_name for estado.

```
estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado, related_name='estado')
```